# Insert csv with variable number of columns for every row into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have this csv file

```
       column1   column2    column3    column4    column5....
row1   value11   value12    value13
row2   value21
row3   value31   value32    value33    value34    value35
row4   value41   value42    value43 
row5   value51   value52
```

All the value's are different. Each row could have from 1 to n columns. My intention is to pass those data to a follow simple MySQL table:

```
row     value
row1    value11
row1    value12
row1    value13
row2    value21
row3    value31
row3    value32
row3    value33
row3    value34
row3    value35
row4    value41 and so on
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be too difficult task for mysql alone. Can't you pre-process the file in some script, unix script, php, java, Ook, ruby, whatever?

Comment: The intention is to use in combination with php in order to fill later some other fields and show the results. So, i could use php to preprocess the file, but not sure how do it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: PHP: open the file, read it line by line, parse by commas, insert into DB value by value.